# Ignore a delimiter from the data using regex

Tags: regex

Previously I was getting the data as below :

```
09/09/2014 12:00:00 AM 840DACHUAY10000100000000712345
```

I was using the below regex to extract nbr_home

```
^.{23}.{11}(?P<nbr_home>.{19})
```

The data has now changed to contain delimiters "|"

```
09/09/2014 12:00:00 AM |840|DACHUAY|10000100000000712345
```

I do not want to change the positional extraction of my existing regex , I just want to modify it in a way so that it ignores the occurrences of delimiters "|"  .

Comment: Can you simply remove all occurrences of `|` before processing?

Comment: Thanks for the response , I am not authorized to modify the data .

Answer (score 2):

You could modify your pattern to match the `|`, but not capture them. Then groups `$1-4` for the string:

```
^(.{23})(?:\|)(.{3})(?:\|)(.{7})(?:\|)(?P<nbr_home>.{20})$
```

example:

**http://regex101.com/r/cV8vZ1/1**

Answer (score 1):

You still would have to post process the capture group to remove `|`
but it will be the correct chars otherwise.

(Just a note that `.{23}.{11}` can be shortened to `.{34}`)

```
 # ^\|?(?:\|?.){23}\|?(?:\|?.){11}\|?(?P<nbr_home>\|?.{19})

 ^ 
 \|?
 (?:
      \|?
      . 
 ){23}
 \|?
 (?:
      \|?
      . 
 ){11}
 \|?
 (?P<nbr_home>
      \|?
      .{19} 
 )
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 56 ) 
09/09/2014 12:00:00 AM |840|DACHUAY|10000100000000712345  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 37 , len 19 ) 
0000100000000712345
```

Comment: I will test the above solution and will let you know...thanks

Comment: No problem. The output is from my tests.